# when two actions happen at the same time, which verb form should be used?

Tags: grammar

> **The girl was lying on the beach .......**
>
> **A**. *and sunbathing*  **B**. *sunbathing*   **C.** *and sunbathe*  **D.** *to sunbath*

I think there is more than one true answer, isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, C is completely incorrect.

A, B and D are all possible depending on what you're trying to say.

A implies two events that may or not be related that you happen to be doing at the same time.

D means that the girl is lying on the beach so she can sunbathe. Meaning that she went to the beach explicitly for the purpose of sunbathing.

B means mostly the same as A, but implies that you are at the beach to sunbath. It is somewhat between A and D.

For context, I'm a native Australian English speaker.

Comment: The part about going to the beach for the purpose of sunbathing is a reasonable assumption; however, she might have gone to the beach primarily to swim, but afterward decided to stay at the beach in order to sunbathe. You could use these same sentences in that circumstance, too.